# How to add a Heroku Django app's new model table to the remote Heroku Postgres with Python migrate?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

After successfully finishing a tutorial on [a Heroku Python app with a Postgres db](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database), I made a new model on my Heroku app, based on the existing code, by copying and pasting the existing model and its table's functions and files. **But I had trouble to actually let Heroku create the table on Postgres remotely.** After some trial-and-error, I found the answer below.

Setup: Heroku Python is running locally and remotely, Heroku Postgres is only running remotely.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to actually create my new table on my remote Heroku Postgres database, by running `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, which was used in the tutorial. But it didn't work right off the bat.  What I needed to do was to set up a few Python files and then run that command at the end.

This works if you edit the model too, such as adding a new field.

All the files I added are into the [Heroku tutorial's code](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started) based on [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database)

This is exactly what I did:

1. in [hello/models.py](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/blob/master/hello/models.py), add

   ```
   class Mytable(models.Model):
       when = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
   ```
2. Let Python generate the `0002_mytable.py` file in my local `hello/migrations` by running the following command on my Mac terminal (which was logged into Heroku and in the virtualenv):

   ```
   python manage.py makemigrations hello
   ```

   and I got this response:

   ```
   Migrations for 'hello':
     0002_mytable.py:
       - Create model Mytable
   ```
3. Add this new migrations file to my remote Heroku

   ```
   git add hello/migrations/0002_mytable.py
   git commit -am "added new migration file"
   git push heroku master
   ```
4. Let Heroku create the table remotely on the remote Heroku Postgres

   ```
   heroku run python manage.py migrate
   ```

   you should see

   ```
   Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ your-heroku-url... up, run.1699
   Operations to perform:
     Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, hello, sessions, auth
   Running migrations:
     Rendering model states... DONE
     Applying hello.0002_mytable... OK
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have made your database migrations locally

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
git add .
git commit -m "Database migrations"
```

Then add the below line as first in your Procfile

```
release: python manage.py migrate
```

Again deploy this changes on heroku

```
git add Procfile
git commit -m "Add Release Phase to Procfile"
git push heroku master
```

Done....